# In pyqt5 browser Createwindows cannot update the url in urlbar

Tags: url, browser, pyqt5, qwebengineview, createwindow

I use Pyqt5 to bulit an easybrowser,in the webpage,most link will built a pop-up window to show new webpages,so I add the code:*def createWindow(self, QWebEnginePage_WebWindowType):* but en issue was followed:new webpage can not update the url in urlbar,and also the back\forward\stop\reload button doesn't work.it Confuse me so much!
here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import tkinter as tk
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # 设置窗口标题
        self.setWindowTitle('My Browser')
        # 设置窗口图标
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icons/penguin.png'))
        # 设置窗口大小900*600
        self.resize(900, 600)
        self.show()

        # 设置浏览器
        self.browser = WebEngineView()
        url = 'http://www.hao123.com'
        # 指定打开界面的 URL
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))
        # 添加浏览器到窗口中

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)


        ###使用QToolBar创建导航栏，并使用QAction创建按钮
        # 添加导航栏
        navigation_bar = QToolBar('Navigation')
        # 设定图标的大小
        navigation_bar.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
        #添加导航栏到窗口中
        self.addToolBar(navigation_bar)
        #QAction类提供了抽象的用户界面action，这些action可以被放置在窗口部件中
        # 添加前进、后退、停止加载和刷新的按钮
        back_button = QAction(QIcon('icons/back.png'), 'Back', self)
        next_button = QAction(QIcon('icons/next.png'), 'Forward', self)
        stop_button = QAction(QIcon('icons/cross.png'), 'stop', self)
        reload_button = QAction(QIcon('icons/renew.png'), 'reload', self)
        back_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        next_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        stop_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.stop)
        reload_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)

        # 将按钮添加到导航栏上
        navigation_bar.addAction(back_button)
        navigation_bar.addAction(next_button)
        navigation_bar.addAction(stop_button)
        navigation_bar.addAction(reload_button)
        #添加URL地址栏
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()
        # 让地址栏能响应回车按键信号
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)

        navigation_bar.addSeparator()
        navigation_bar.addWidget(self.urlbar)

        #让浏览器相应url地址的变化
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.renew_urlbar)

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
        if q.scheme() == '':
            q.setScheme('http')
        self.browser.setUrl(q)

    def renew_urlbar(self, q):
    #     # 将当前网页的链接更新到地址栏
         self.urlbar.setText(q.toString())
         self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0)





class WebEngineView(QWebEngineView):
    windowList = []

    # 重写createwindow()
    def createWindow(self, QWebEnginePage_WebWindowType):
        new_webview = WebEngineView()
        new_window = MainWindow()

        new_window.setCentralWidget(new_webview)
        new_window.show()

        self.windowList.append(new_window)  # 注：没有这句会崩溃！！！
        return new_webview




    # 创建应用

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication.instance()
    # 创建主窗口
    window=MainWindow()
    # 显示窗口
    window.show()
    # 运行应用，并监听事件
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please avoid non english comments in your examples (especially if they don't use ascii characters) as they are distracting and not even readable for most of us, and make reading your code more confusing or difficult.

Comment: Please continue to use non English comments in your example code, as they help to show us what you consider important in your code and how you group lines. They make your code interesting and easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the new window correctly, but you also set a new webview for that window while it already has one.
Just return its existing `browser` webview instead of creating a new one.

```
class WebEngineView(QWebEngineView):
    windowList = []

    def createWindow(self, QWebEnginePage_WebWindowType):
        new_window = MainWindow()

        new_window.show()

        self.windowList.append(new_window)
        return new_window.browser
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. For a beginner, your help can inspire me to continue to study hard.

Comment: @jianfengding you're very welcome, and it's good to know to be inspiring in that way :-) Remember that, if my answer solved your problem, you can set it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark under the vote arrows, on the left of the answer itself.